# Does Snowflake keep track of the warehouse resizing values?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, admin

I'm looking at `WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY`, but I can't find a way to track the warehouse resizing values.

How can I get this data out of Snowflake?

(based on a customer question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To track the resizing values you can join `WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY` with `QUERY_HISTORY` on `query_id`, and parse the `sql_text`:

```sql
use role accountadmin
;

select timestamp, event_state, a.user_name, a.role_name,
    upper(regexp_substr(b.query_text, '(XSMALL|SMALL|MEDIUM|LARGE|XLARGE|XXLARGE|XXXLARGE|X4LARGE|X5LARGE|X6LARGE)', 1, 1, 'i')) as wh_size,
    upper(regexp_substr(b.query_text, '(STANDARD|ECONOMY)', 1, 1, 'i')) as scaling_policy
from snowflake.account_usage.WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY a
join snowflake.account_usage.QUERY_HISTORY b 
on a.query_id = b.query_id
where a.event_name = 'ALTER_WAREHOUSE'
and a.timestamp > '2021-10-01'
```

[image]

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_events_history.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

---

If you are thinking about analyzing costs, check:

- https://medium.com/opendoor-labs/analyze-snowflake-costs-570b7be953db

Comment: there is also a wharehouse size on all executed sql in the query_history, so you can see the "edges" over time to infer charge that way also.  Which can be handy if the warehouse is resized via `CREATE OR REPLACE` with different sizes.

Comment: That's a good tip, thanks @SimeonPilgrim!